# Google Maps with Python 3.4.1

Tags: python, google-maps, python-3.4

I am trying to write a script to assign the Latitude and Longitude of a location based on the address similar to what is fantastically explained here:
http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net
The only problem is that, that code is written for Python 2.3-2.6. Does anyone know how I would update this to work with Python 3.4.1?

When I run

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
```

I get the error

```
No module named 'googlemaps'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to install it using python3 pip?  If it's not available from pypi for py3, you're only option will be to try to port the code yourself.  8-(

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with having two versions of python installed on your system (they will not interfere w/ each other), so why not just install py2.7 and use that environment?

Comment: @user590028 I have to use Python 3.4.1 for this project. Can you please give me a link to the method you are talking about?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using Python 2to3 tool, and it worked just fine:
`2to3 googlemaps.py -w`

About error `No module named 'googlemaps'`. You have to place `googlemaps.py` into any PYTHONPATH directory. You may use local directory, or you may manually copy `googlemaps.py` to site-packages folder.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help - its working now. Do you have any suggestions about how to get an API key? I have signed up for a few but they all keep returning the error:NameError: name 'MY API KEY' is not defined

Comment: @ben, you get this error, because you haven't defined your API key variable. Somewhere in your code you have to define a variable `MY_API_KEY = "<your-api-key-here>"`

Comment: @ben, if this has answered your question, you should consider accepting the answer. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip-3.2 install flask-googlemaps
```